# How to get last instance of an array built from for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flickr

I'm using a for loop to search api results and build an array of objects so I can use that data and append it to the DOM. I'm doing this because Flickr's API's results aren't consistent to their values. For example, I'm looking for "aperture" and sometimes it's index number is [9], sometimes it's [11], and so on. I'm not sure if there's another way to achieve the results I'm looking for. I figured I could just loop through the results and search for the values I need.

Is there a way to grab only the last instance of the array? As it is now if I were to call exifArray[9].aperture it would show the result multiple times and also as undefined when the loop hasn't reached that part yet. I attempted to move the console.log(exifArray) to just outside of the for loop so it wouldn't repeat but it just returns the empty array that was declared at the top of the function.

Here's a screen shot of the console and also a code snippet:

```
Flickr.prototype.exifData = function(results) {
    var apiKey = '';
    var self = this;
    var exifArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<results.photos.photo.length; i++) {
    var currentId = results.photos.photo[i].id;
    var exifData = $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getExif&api_key=" + apiKey + "&photo_id=" + currentId + "&format=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    type: "GET",
    })
.done(function(exifResults) {
        var options = {};   
     if (exifResults.stat === "ok") {
    for (var x=0; x<exifResults.photo.exif.length; x++) {


        var labelArray = exifResults.photo.exif[x].label;
             if (labelArray === 'Model') {
                options.cameraType = exifResults.photo.exif[x].raw._content;
             } else if (labelArray === 'Lens Model') {
                options.lensModel = exifResults.photo.exif[x].raw._content; 
             }  else if (labelArray === 'Exposure') {
                options.exposure = exifResults.photo.exif[x].raw._content;
             } else if (labelArray === 'Aperture') {
                options.aperture = exifResults.photo.exif[x].raw._content;
             } else if (labelArray === 'ISO Speed') {
                options.iso = exifResults.photo.exif[x].raw._content;
             } else {continue}
             }
        }
        exifArray.push(options);
        console.log(exifArray);
        if (exifResults.stat === "ok") {
        self.content.renderExifData(exifArray);
        }
    })
}
```

}

[image: console.log of results]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
var lastItem = arr.pop();
```

Comment: I attempted this but my issue is var lastItem = arr.pop(); also keeps repeating itself. I tried to use pop inside the function: self.content.renderExifData(exifArray); but it's also being looped. It returns the last element of each array. I can't seem to get the values from exifArray without it being looped wherever I try to take it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which element you want to get. But obviously you should use pop() not in a loop but when your final array is built. Like you said you have to use array[9] or array [11] - that's exactly the place where you should use array.pop() instead